# Replace some chars in Form fields in .Net Core Request, C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to replace all `۱` chars with `1` in my web api .Net Core requests?
e.g:
`Number ۱` should convert to `Number 1`
In MVC 5 I used `HttpModule`, in .net core I used Middleware as follows:

```
namespace VistaBest.Api
{
    public class PersianCharsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public PersianCharsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var collection = httpContext.Request.Form;
            foreach (var controlKey in collection.Keys.Where(controlKey => !controlKey.StartsWith("__")))
            {
                collection[controlKey] = collection[controlKey].ToString().Replace("۱", "1");
            }
            return _next(httpContext);
        }
    }

    public static class PersianCharsMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UsePersianCharsMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<PersianCharsMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

But `collection[controlKey]` is Readonly and I can't assign value to it?
Actually, I have to edit all string fields of form, How should I do it?
Can I do it with custom model binder?

Comment: @mjwills I have to standard all numbers chars in string fields and convert them to English

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify HttpContext.Request.Form in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701311/how-to-modify-httpcontext-request-form-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I could write it with custom Model Binder, See answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could write it with custom model binder:

```
public class PersianCharsModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private readonly IModelBinder _simpleTypeModelBinder;
    public PersianCharsModelBinder(IModelBinder simpleTypeModelBinder)
    {
        _simpleTypeModelBinder = simpleTypeModelBinder;
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None) return _simpleTypeModelBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);
        var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueAsString)) return _simpleTypeModelBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
        var model = valueAsString.ToEnglishNumber().RemoveArabicChars();
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class PersianCharsBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType) return null;
        var simpleTypeModelBinder = new SimpleTypeModelBinder(context.Metadata.ModelType);
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string)) return new PersianCharsModelBinder(simpleTypeModelBinder);
        return simpleTypeModelBinder;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new PersianCharsBinderProvider());
            });
```